# Помогите разобраться, правильно ли стоят знаки препинания! Если нет, то почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Но, несмотря на все это, он не забывал «свою историю».

Comment: А зачем кавычки?

Comment: это неважно, вопрос про пунктуацию

Comment: Нет, важно, это тоже пунктуация. И вообще, всё важно. ;)